# Make multiple divs with same class work at same time through javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I have two divs with same class name:

```
<div class="bubble" style="margin-bottom: 160px">
        <p>bubble1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="bubble">
        <p>bubble2</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can i apply javascript so that both of them works simultaneously. Right now only the first one works and nothing happens on the second one.

Comment: What do you want to do to them *"simultaneously"*?

Comment: You cant. However things can happen very close after each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no true simultaneous operations in JavaScript. Yet, each operation or iteration happens in milliseconds, close enough. You can loop over the matches.

```
var bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble'); // get all divs with class bubble

[].forEach.call(bubbles, function(bubble){
    // do something to bubble
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code to achieve what you wanted.

```
var bubbles = document.querySelectorAll('.bubble');
for(var i=0; bubbles[i]; i++){
    var bubble =  bubbles[i];
    // now you do whatever you want to do with bubble 
    // i.e bubble.style.marginLeft = "10px";
}
```

Or you can just use jQuery to do the same. Its just one line code

```
$('.bubble').css({marginLeft:10});
```

Thanks

Comment: `bubbles` is `NodeList`. It does not have method `forEach`.

Comment: Ops! Thanks @AdamAzad for pointing out the problem. Edited my code. Although, your answer looks more elegant then me.

Answer (score 0):

```
var x=document.getElementsByClassName('bubble');

//now x is an array of all elements with the class bubble

for(i=0;i<=x.length-1;i++){
    //Do operations accordingly
}
```